# How to change JTable Drag & Drop Detection Time?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to change the detection time for drag and drop functionality on JTables?

```
    sampleJTable.setDragEnabled(true);
    sampleJTable.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT_ROWS);
    sampleJTable.setTransferHandler(new TableRowTransferHandler(sampleJTable));
```

The detection time in tables is very long, about 1 second. Anything less and you'd simply select a bunch of rows.

Is there any way to make it detect the drag and drop action faster, for example, as it does with drag and drop lists?

Thanks